# In ReactJS does my code have backing instances and therefore can use refs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I tend to write my ReactJS components by assembling bits of JSX together, example below.

I read this page https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html which says "Refs may not be attached to a stateless function, because the component does not have a backing instance"

What I am wondering is whether the code I am writing means I am writing stateless functions that do not have backing instances?

Or does my code have backing instances and therefore can use refs

I would like to be able to have refs to DOM elements, like:

```
    <input
      onChange={() = {console.log(e)}
      ref=**some ref callback function**
      value="rabbit"
    />
```

But I wonder if this is even possible given the coding approach I am taking.

example:

```
    import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react'

    export default class Blah extends React.Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
      }

      makeAnimal = () => {
        let animaltype = 'furry'
        if (animaltype === 'furry') {
          return (
            <input
              onChange={() = {console.log(e)}
              value="rabbit"
            />
          )
        } else {
          return (
            <input
              onChange={() = {console.log(e)}
              value="fish"
            />
          )
        }
      }

      makeForm = () => {
        let section = {}

        section.floob = (
            <input
              onChange={() = {console.log(e)}
              value="floob"
            />
        )

        section.flub = (
            <input
              onChange={() = {console.log(e)}
              value="flub"
            />
        )

        if (true) {
          return (
            <div>
              {section.flub}
            </div>
          )
        } else {
          return (
            <div>
              {section.floob}
              {this.makeAnimal()}
            </div>
          )
        }
      }


      render() {

        let section = {}

        section.extras = (
          <div>
            <h1>
              The heading!
            </h1>


    </div>
    )

    return (
      <div>
        {section.extras}
        {this.makeForm()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to attach a `ref` function to a pure HTML `<input>` component?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I had a look again at the documentation and turns out that you can attach a ref to a Dom element.  I removed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating your components via classes therefore they are not stateless. A stateless component would look something like:

```
export default function Blah({ someProp, someOtherProp }) {
    return (
        <div>
            {someProp}
        </div>
    );
}
```

So in your code there keeping refs should work, however, the `<input>` component is stateless as it's not a react component, see wintvelt's answer below.

Comment: That's strange.  I only ever get undefined when I try to access a DOM element via ref

Comment: See wintvelt's comment below